Grouping a set of LayoutContent into one LayoutDocument
I'm reading the wiki for AvalonDock and I can't figure out a way to group a set of LayoutContent into a workspace (my terminology) such that I can dock the entire workspace and it maintains the layout of the LayoutContent within the workspace.
Is this even possible?
I believe I could use a DockManager for each workspace, but this wouldn't allow me to drag LayoutContent between the individual DockManager for the workspaces (as far as I can see.)
Is it possible to achieve the desired outcome using AvalonDock?
